# How to space and have 3 different text on the sameline(footer)

Tags: html, css

Here is the text

1. @2017 ABCD
2. All Rights reserved
3. some text

Now I want this all in the footer, but 1. to the left 2. in the center and 3 in the right , how do i go about and accomplish this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: flex + justify-content:space-between. a little search here or on a search engines and you'll find plenty usefull information. None of your HTML or CSS stands here to show what you tried ... is this a job offer :) ?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This way you have more control over each section styling aspects.

```css
#footer {
  width: 100%;
}

#footer-inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.year,
.middle,
.some-text {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div id="footer-inner">
    <div class="year">
      @2017 ABCD
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
      All Rights reserved
    </div>
    <div class="some-text">
      some text some text some text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="mylist">

<li> @2017 ABCD </li> 
<li> All Rights reserved </li>
<li> some text </li>

</ul>
```

in css:

```
.mylist li{
display:inline-block;
}
```